# What size should an image be for printing a very large (10m x 2m) banner

Tags: print-design, images, resolution, dpi, ppi

I work as a graphic designer and until know I have worked only in vector. Now I have to do a very big banner like a landscape and I have to use a photo for this. What is an acceptable resolution for an image for a 10m x 2m banner?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest contacting the vendor for the reqirements.